# Modular Arithmetic For Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I'm teaching myself modular arithmetic but cannot seem to find any good resources on modular arithmetic regarding polynomials modulo $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How does one solve

$$P(x) \quad\text{mod}n$$
where $P(x)$ is a polynomial with real number coefficients and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For example
$$7x^3+4x^2+8x-9 \quad \text{mod}4$$
Do we just reduce the coefficients $\text{mod} 4$? Any explantion or sources help. Thanks

Comment: yes, you can reduce the coefficients mod 4, and then you only have 4 cases to test; plug in $0,1,2,3$ in $x$ in $P(x)$, and see if for which values, if any, you get $0$

Comment: @Albert So this would leave us with $3x^3+3$? Is that a correct answer?

Comment: By 'solve' do you mean reduce to a canonical (least terms) form, or do you mean find the roots?  Are you familiar with congruences or rings & ideals?

Comment: @BillDubuque I would like it reduced but still in polynomial form. Not find roots. I would love some sources on congruences or rings & ideals...

Comment: @MakoJ you can factorise further: this is $(x+1)(3x^2+x+3)$ (mod $4$)

Comment: It is not clear if yor are considering polynomial functions, or formal polynomials, and this distinction does matter. See my comments on Piquito's answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Certainly a first step will be reducing coefficients modulo $n$. Secondly, I guess you have to try with the primes dividing $n$ for then using Chinese remainder theorem. For this a fundamental result is the following:

Let be $f(x)=a_nx^n +a_ {n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ and $p$ a prime.The congruence $f(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ is equivalent to the congruence $f(x)\equiv R(x)\pmod p$ where $R(x)$ is the remainder of dividing $f(x)$ by $x^p-x$.

In fact, we have $$f(x)=(x^p-x)Q(x)+R(x)$$ where the degree of $R(x)$ is at most equal to $p-1$. Since $x^p-x\equiv0\pmod p$ you do have the property.

Comment: OP did not say that $P(x)$ denotes a polynomial *function*, so  $x^p = x$ is not true.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque.- When the O.P, writes **where P(x) is a polynomial with real number coefficients** it is clear that he referres to the (very good) ring $\mathbb Q[x]$ instead of $\mathbb R[x]$ because, for example, it would be meaningless the equation $$\sqrt2x^9+\pi x+2x-\sqrt5=0\pmod7$$

Comment: It seems you misunderstood my comment - which has nothing to do with what you wrote above. Do you understand the difference between (formal) polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]\,$ vs. polynomial functions on $\Bbb Z_p?\  $ In the former ring $\,x^p\neq x\,$ but they are equal  as functions on $\Bbb Z_p.\ \ $

Comment: What you and the OP want with the polynomial $P(x)$ are different, but for what you or he want anyway, we have $P(x)=(x^p-x)Q(x)+R(x)$. For some goals, in particular for the OP wants to know,  $P(x)$ can be reduced to $R(x)$ which is very useful.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the OP "wants" they have not answered my comment inquiring about such. It is *extremely* common for beginners to confuse formal polynomials and polynomial functions so one cannot generally make any assumptions about what is actually sought.